# when hover on element then view button will pop-up in react.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an array of articles, and I render those articles using "map()" method in React,
I want that when I hover on the article one by one then the view button will pop up on the element right alignment.[Here is the requirement video]:[image]

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16zMGoKu4_H91tQJrRAEkuMTEnZTv4k-k/view?usp=sharing

it will you help to understand the problem.

Comment: Just set the css display to none for the button and when hover display it and add the styles for it

Comment: i tried but it not work in my case.

Comment: i tried but it not work in my case.

Comment: You need to add a minimum reproducible piece of code showing your attempt so, that people can guide you. I tried looking at the link and I'm not sure what is that so I'm not gonna download it. otherwise you can make of codesandbox of it and add the link